# Getting dents while using subsurf modifier without using mirror modifier

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, subdivision-surface

[image]

Why am i getting dents all of a sudden while using subdivision surface modifier?
And also i did not use mirror modifier.

Comment: You may have an unwanted "face" inside your mesh.

Comment: As @Dontwalk mentioned you have likely got additional geometry such as very narrow additional faces or loops. Try highlighting all in Edit mode and select Remove Doubles.

Comment: This is generally not about using Mirror modifier, it's about internal faces in the mesh which cut surface smoothed with Subsurf. They can be caused by Mirror modifier or by any other way but their effect is the same